# findViewById(); com uma variável dentro do método

Tags: android, button

Tipo assim:

```
public void main(){
  String a = "bt1";   
  Button bt1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.a);   
}
```

Sei que isso não funciona, mas seria mais ou menos assim, usar uma variável `String`.

Comment: O seu objetivo é obter uma `View` com base no seu nome ? Ou seja na String que representa o id ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não, não é possível. É necessário passar o ID (que é um `int`), para capturar a `View` através do método `findViewById`, mas você pode utilizar um método semelhante.

Com o [**findViewWithTag**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#findViewWithTag(java.lang.Object)) você consegue capturar as `view` que possuem uma `tag`.

Basta adicionar o atributo `android:tag="custom"` em sua `view`. Ex:

**Layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/viewPrincipal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="148dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="@string/btn_login"
        android:tag="tagDaView" <!-- Sua Tag -->
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Material.Light"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Java:**

```
String tag = "tagDaView";

View viewPrincipal = findViewById(R.id.viewPrincipal);
Button button = viewPrincipal.findViewWithTag( tag );

System.out.println( button.getText() );
```

Comment: Isso me ajudou bastante.... obrigado

Answer (score 0):

pra pessoas que possam estar com esta dúvida atualmente, a partir de uma activity é possivel localizar um id por meio de uma string usando `getResources().getIdentifier()` e depois é possível usar essa `id` localizada pra achar a `view`.

em kotlin fica:

```
val id = activity.resources.getIdentifier(idString, "id", activity.packageName)
val view: View? = activity.findViewById(id)
```

se o `id` não existir `getIdentifier()` retorna 0 e o `findViewById()` vai retornar nulo se procurar com esse id

eu utilizo isso para testes quando eu não quero pressupor que a `view` exista. Se fosse usar `R.id.idString`, e não existisse essa `view` o teste não ia `buildar`.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).